# How to use multiple iptable rules in chef

Tags: linux, chef-infra, iptables

So I was trying to write multiple iptables for blocking certain subnets and it turns out that the very last iptables rule is only getting implemented.
This is what I've put in the recipe:

```
execute "block_ports" do
    command "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 1> --dport <port> -j DROP"
    command "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 2> --dport <port> -j DROP"
    command "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <subnet 3> --dport <port> -j DROP"
end
```

Can someone please tell me how to write multiple iptables rules so that all get executed in Linux (preferably Chef)?

Thanks!

Comment: See in particular the second half of the accepted answer to the linked duplicate, describing how to provide a heredoc with any arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: That said -- back in the day, I wrote a [shorewall Chef cookbook](https://github.com/Tippr/tippr-public-cookbooks/tree/master/shorewall) for a former employer, and I'd strongly suggest using something like it rather than running individual iptables commands yourself. Using a proper firewall framework lets you write higher-level rules; that one particular is built to be easy to use with Chef's search tooling, so you can, say, tell your database port to search for application servers and open a port only for systems that are found by that search.

Comment: Will take a look. Thanks for your response!